# Could not parse '[{"created_at":"2021-11-20T15:14:28.000000Z"}]'. How can i parse a date to carbon?

Tags: php, laravel

error: Could not parse '[{"created_at":"2021-11-20T15:14:28.000000Z"}]': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string ([{"created_at":"2021-11-20T15:14:28.000000Z"}]) at position 0 ([): Unexpected character

**Controller** :

```
$created_at = $ar->where('status', 0)->get('created_at');  
$backlog = Carbon::parse($created_at)->format('y-m-d');
```

i was trying to get the auto generated created_at in my database and add 3 days on it and so far i only saw the carbon way which is to parse it with carbon and then use the addDays() but unfortunately the system sees the whole column name and time. How can i parse an auto generated timestamp?

Comment: what is `$ar` here?

Comment: its the connection from the model

Answer (score 2):

because you need to decode it first:

```
  $value= json_decode('[{"created_at":"2021-11-20T15:14:28.000000Z"}]')[0]->created_at;
  $parsedValue=Carbon::parse($value);
```

then you can use $parsedValue in your query as usual

Comment: it worked but this part "'[{"created_at":"2021-11-20T15:14:28.000000Z"}]'" made me confused because that one is the value of created_at. i will be decoding every new created at. how can i make it more automatic?

update:

Comment: oh nvm i did this "$value= json_decode($created_at)[0]->created_at;" thank you so much!

Comment: @MyJinji why your code encoded as json?

Comment: @sta i honestly dont know

Comment: i have another question. What if there was no data captured in @created_at? it gave me an error when it does. 

error: Undefined array key 0

Comment: then you could write: if ($created_at!=null) then  $value= json_decode($created_at) . . .

Comment: Is there a way where i can state if created_at >= updated_at - 3 days in this code.
$created_at = $ar->where('status', 0)->get('created_at');
$updated_at = $ar->where('status', 0)->get('updated_at');

cuz i needed to find the number of rows that did not got updated after 3 days.

Comment: yes, you can use somthing like:
->whereRaw('DATE_SUB(updated_at, INTERVAL 3 DAY)>created_at')
more in https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp

Comment: thank you for the resource but ive done what your wrote like this -- $created_at = $ar->where('status', 0)->value('created_at');
        $updated_at = $ar->where('status', 0)->whereRaw('DATE_SUB(updated_at, INTERVAL 3 DAY)>created_at'); -- and it gave me an error: htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string,

Answer (score 0):

You can get a specific the column from the first row of a result set using the `value` query builder method. In your case:

```
$backlog = $ar->where('status', 0)->value('created_at');
```

If your model is properly defined this should already be a Carbon instance or null if there are no results in the result set.